# Sign of $\partial_x(\sigma^2p)(t,0)$ with $p$ solving some Fokker-Planck equation

Tags: parabolic-pde

Let $\rho : \mathbb R_+\to\mathbb R_+$ be a density (as good as possible), i.e.

$$\int_0^\infty \rho(x)dx=1.$$

Consider the parabolic PDE

$$\partial_t p(t,x) = \frac{1}{2}\partial_{xx}^2\big(\sigma^2(t,x)p(t,x)\big)- \partial_x\big(b(t,x)p(t,x)\big),\quad \forall (t, x)\in(0,\infty)\times(0,\infty),$$

together with the conditions $p(0,\cdot)=\rho$ and $p(\cdot,0)=0$. Assuming $b,\sigma$ are as nice as possible (bounded, Lipschitz, non degenerate), how can we show for all $t>0$

$$\partial_x(\sigma^2p)(t,0) ~\ge~ 0?$$

I was told that when $\sigma\equiv \sigma(t)$ and $b\equiv b(t)$, this follows from the Zaremba-Giraud theorem. I look for more general references.

Any answer, comments are references are highly appreciated

Comment: This follows from the maximum principle.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy Thank you very kindly for the answer. Do you mind giving more details? Indeed I'm not familiar with the relevant results. According to my understanding, the maximum principle (or comparaison principle) yields $p\ge 0$. As for my desired result, I set $q:=\sigma^2p$ and I obtain a PDE $\partial_t q = \sigma^2\partial^2_{xx}q/2 -b\partial_xq + [\cdots]q$, but I don't see why $\partial_x q(t,0)\ge 0$...

Comment: @MichaelRenardy I will really appreciate if you can provide an answer

Comment: $q$ is nonnegative and vanishes at 0.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy Thanks again for your reply. Could you please give me a reference ensuring that $p\ge 0$? In addition, do $q\ge 0$ and $q(t,0)=0$ imply $\partial_x q(t,0)\ge 0$ for the case where $p$ is just a weak solution?